# Internal link without id in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

If we need to jump to top section then we can simple write a code

```
<a href="#top">link to top</a>
```

or just javascript code

```
location.href=#top
```

Result : It takes us to top page with url :http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#top.

But what my problem is, I dont' want to show /#top query on url string but i want my page to that top section . Reason why i don't want to show that string in url is, my page get stuck if browser don't find 'id' named top .Context or information which i'm displaying is inside a dialog box so that once the dialog box is closed there isn't any id named top then when user tries to refresh that page i.e http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#top , page gets stuck .

Can anyone give a better solution for this problem?

Comment: If there is no such element - where do you want to rewind to?

Comment: initial there is a pop up dialog box where there is some information and id named top is also present there. but when user close that dialog box , url remain same i.e http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#top so when user refresh the browser then blank page is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(".link").on("click", function(e) {
  $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(".link").not(this).offset().top}, 500);
  return false
})
```

```css
#top, #bottom {
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background:blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background:orange;
}

span {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="top">top <span class="link">go to bottom</span></div>
<div id="bottom">bottom <span class="link">go to top</span></div>
```

Comment: $(".dialogImport").animate({scrollTop: $("#info").not(this).offset().top}, 500); 
i wrote this on my console window . I did get my content but scroll isn't working . any solution for this??

Comment: Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: it worked , my bad. 
dialogImport should be replaced with modal-body. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

You have few options...

You can use pure Javscript:

`window.scrollTo(X, Y);` (obvisourly X and Y are the scroll coordinates, and top will be 0,0).

Another option (yet non-jQuery based) can be:

`document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

If you prefer jQuery based solution, try the following:

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

Or, as well:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Use the option that better suit your need.

Enjoy coding.

Comment: Thanks for answer . I found that it does scroll in window browser but my intention is to scroll my dialog box . Anyways i have upvoted your answer as i did learn new thing. THanks

Comment: Question: do you have to "remove" the dialog object from the DOM? Can't you simply HIDE it? Maybe use "display:none"?
Another question: why not put the #reference outside the dialog?

Comment: Since its a pop up its hard to hide that dom element . #reference can be placed outside as i want to display only when user click some option.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/owLm5zcq/)

**Html**

```
 <div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
    Test
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
    Test 2
</div>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                //});
            });
        });
```