# Redirect to other page and scroll to specified element without showing id in URL

Tags: html, redirect, anchor

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500294/7739518) answer doesn't really answer the question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113990/internal-link-without-id-in-url) only works on the same page;

**How to redirect a user to another page** (from the same domain) **and scroll to a specified element upon clicking an `anchor` tag, without showing the `#id` in the URL?**

I do not need any smooth animation and *If possible* I would like to do it without JS/jQuery.

Comment: Do you control the page to which you are redirecting the user?

Comment: @OliverRadini Yes.

Comment: Would you be willing to have extra parameters in the url?

Comment: @OliverRadini If they disappear within a split second after loading the page, yes.

Comment: You mention that you'd like to do it without JS; do you mean that? I'm not sure it's technically possible without javascript

Comment: @OliverRadini If possible, without, otherwise with as little JS as possible.

Comment: @und3rdg Same domain.

Comment: From what I know it has to be either a parameter in the URL going to the ID in DOM or you use javascript and save the ID to local storage which you then on page load read and jump to desired position.

Answer (score 0):

This i think is simplest solution. You checking last url, if it is match use JS to calculate position of element and scroll to it.

```
var fromUrl = document.referrer

if (fromUrl === "http://www.fromWhereImComming.com/site") {
  var position = document.getElementById('nav-tags').getBoundingClientRect().height
  scroll(0, position)
}
```

If you have more url's from where you can come, you need 2 scripts. 
One on refer page where you want to save some variable to local storage.
You need to bind it to link with something, for example with simple onclick

```
<a href="" onclick="saveToLocalStorage()">link</a>
<script>
    function saveToLocalStorage(){
        localStorage.setItem("scroll", "true")
    }
</script>
```

Second one is similar to first approach, but instead checking url, check local storage, use it and clean it.

```
<script>
    var isScroll = localStorage.getItem("scroll");

    if (isScroll === "true") {
      var position = document.getElementById('nav-tags').getBoundingClientRect().height
      scroll(0, position)
      localStorage.removeItem("scroll")
    }
</script>
```